# WinSat command line closes too fast

Tags: windows-7, command-line, winsat, windows-experience-index

I'm trying to do some analysis under Windows 7 as to why I can't get a Windows Experience Index (WEI) rating due to disk issues. To this end, I'm trying to run **winsat** from the command line with :-

```
winsat disk -seq -read -drive c
```

and

```
winsat disk -ran -write -n 2
```

but the command window is closing too quickly to be able to read the results.  I've tried opening a seperate **cmd** window to run it in but it still insists on launching its own window to run in, closing straight away.

Any idea how I can see the output?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could redirect output to a file so you can read it.

example:

```
winsat disk -seq -read -drive c > C:\winsatoutput.txt 2>&1
```

**EDIT**: It seems winsat has a -log switch which does this:

```
winsat disk -seq -read -drive -log C:\winsatoutput.txt
```

this way, **all output** including errors will be in the file `C:\winsatoutput.txt`.

Comment: other window still spawns and closes on finish, 0 file length on output file

Comment: I'm almost there, but the log output isn't plain ASCII.  Gonna dig into it a bit

Comment: Ah, there's a readable log at **c:\Windows\Performance\WinSAT** that includes my command-line ones.

Answer (score 29):

I had the same problem but it resolved when I ran "cmd" as administrator, then typed the winsat commands in the command prompt box.

Comment: Wow, this answer should be on top, and actually _answers the question._  StackExchange is so dumb to not allow sorting by vote.

Comment: amazing, that actually works. wtf

Answer (score 4):

Open the *Start* menu and type `cmd`, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (or right-click it and select *Run as admin*) to open an elevated command-prompt. Run winsat from there and you will see the results without the window closing as soon as it finishes running.

Answer (score 3):

there is a parameter -xml , which saves the output to a xml file.

see http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc742157(WS.10).aspx
.

for example: 
`WinSAT disk –read –ran –ransize 4096 –drive k -xml C:\test.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't do that over here - but try:

```
winsat disk -seq -read -drive c & pause
```

Comment: Alas, that calls pause in the calling window, i.e., the cmd window that I run winsat from.

Comment: Sounds like whatever's happening is very weird indeed.

Comment: Yea i thought the `& pause` should also work.. but it calls it and only shows the output `press any key to continue` .. it does not actually pause.